# JavaScript Regexp matching "a\"b"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm implementing a lexer with JavaScript Regexp, one of the token types is double quoted string, such as "abc". The complex case is string with escaped quote character, like "a\"b".

I assume the following 2 regexps are equivalent: 
1) `"(\\"|[^"])*"` 
2) `"([^"]|\\")*"`

But actually only the #1 works. You can try the 2 regexps against "a\"b" on http://regex101.com/#javascript. I don't know what's the difference between the two, and is there any better solution?

PS: it turns out that #1 and #2 are different, see the following simplified example:

```
regex = /(a|ab)*/
regex.exec("aab") -> matches "aa"
```

JavaScript Regexp will not try to match as long as possible, it only tries to find a feasible matching.

While the following one works, because "aa" is not a matching.

```
regex = /^(a|ab)*$/
regex.exec("aab") -> matches "aab"
```

Comment: If only there were a tool even _more_ powerful than regexes. I think, if I were to invent such a beast, I would call it a parser :-)

Comment: I hope you realize your regex is essentially (.)*

Comment: @Etai Really? I don't think so, the first one doesn't match """, I just tried it on regex101.

Comment: Really. Are you inputting the string version or the regex version there? It works for me... (\"|[^"])*